# Converting a geopandas geometry into a shapleys polygon

Tags: gis, geopandas, shapely

I am extremely new to python in general, but come from a decent programming background in Fortran and Matlab. I'm trying to figure out what seems to be a simple task:

I am importing a Shapefile using GeoPandas `read_file` command. It comes in with no problem, and includes the geometry column that contains the polygon represented by all the vertices as you would expect. The data is a single row.

What I need is a Shapely's Polygon to pass into py3dep so I can gather the spatial rasters I need, and I cannot figure out how to translate the geometry entry into a polygon.

The solution has to be simple, but I've been searching for hours, trying a thousand different things, all to no avail. If anyone could help with a simple demonstration I'd be eternally grateful.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do, I've verified the code works when I pass it the tuple, and fails if I try to pass "shape" to "geom" as shape is not a shapelys polygon. (I understand this is a lame attempt and is just shown as "what I'm trying to do")

**UPDATED CODE BELOW TO WORKING** based on solution provided by @PaulH

```
import py3dep
import geopandas as gpd


shape = gpd.read_file("inputshape.shp")
print(shape.type)

geom = shape.loc[0, 'geometry']
dem = py3dep.get_map("DEM", geom, resolution=10, geo_crs="epsg:4326", crs="epsg:3857", output_dir="raster")
```

Comment: A list of all polygons can be obtained by `your_gpdf.geometry.values`.

Comment: @swatchai I get the list showing a geometry array mem location, but no way (that I can manage) to pass that array?

Comment: Please post your relevant code, and study how to ask a good question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @osop make sure you have the recent version of GeoPandas (0.9.0).

Comment: @swatchai, I've tried to adhere better to the guide and add more information. Thanks for sending that, I initially figured my question was so basic it would need no further information.

Comment: @martinfleis: verified 0.9.0

Comment: `geom = shape.loc[0, 'geometry']`

Comment: @PaulH - That worked! Thank you. I've updated my code up top to what is working for posterity.

Comment: @PaulH Please consider adding your very helpful comment as an answer.